# Finding closest point with Theano

Tags: python, theano

among a set of weight vector how could I find the closest to a given instance vector in optimize theano way. Or do I need to use numpy?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on Theano mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/J-l9UmpSG2Y